# The relationship between semidirect product and free product

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, semidirect-product, free-product

If we define $\mathbb{Z}\ltimes G$ to be $\mathbb{Z}\times G$, with multiplication as
$$
(a,g)*(b,h)=(a+b,g^a\cdot h)
$$
I want to show that $\mathbb{Z}\ltimes G$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}*G$(free product) by the relation $tg=gt$, where $t$ is the generator of $\mathbb{Z}$.
I am thinking to define a map $(a,g)\mapsto(a,g)$ under the quotient. But I don’t think it will satisfy the multiplication.

I am really confused with the free products, sign. Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying you're confused by the use of the same symbol $*$ for the multiplication operation between elements in the semidirect product and the free product operation between two groups? If so, just introduce a different symbol for the former.  Also, the quotient of the free product by $tg=gt$ for all $g\inG$ would not be the semidirect product but the direct product.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Yes, it should be the direct product. I am confused about how to construct the multiplication of free product in order to make it isomorphic to the direct product.

Comment: You don't construct the multiplication in the free product; that multiplication is given to you as part of the definition of "free product". Also, the direct product is not (for nontrivial $G$) isomorphic to the free product but rather to the quotient of the free product given by the relations $tg=gt$ mentioned in your message and in my previous comment.

Comment: Sorry, I was meaning isomorphic to the quotient. Could you say more specifically about how to construct the isomorphism?

Comment: The isomorphism sends the pair $(n,g)$ in the direct product to the coset of the word $ng$ in the free product.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thanks, I finally understand the isomorphism!